# How to test a stored procedure with LINQTOSQL

Tags: sql-server, linq, unit-testing, linq-to-sql, integration-testing

Can someone please tell me how you're supposed to test a stored procedure given that the LINQ datacontext.CreateDatabase() I use to create my test database doesn't create the stored procedure.

It seems difficult to test it in your test procedure if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Is this a rhetorical question?  What does unit testing a stored procedure have to do with linq to sql?

Comment: I create my database using the LINQTOSQL method CreateDatabase(). I then populate it with some data and run the tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're supposed to create your stored procedure first, then add it to your L2S context, then just call it in a unit test.  Of course you'll want to set up a special test database first.  Also, obviously, be sure to clean up your database after *each* test to minimize side effects *between* tests.

Comment: I *think* you mean 'supposed to create your stored procedure first, then...'

Comment: If you mean manually add the stored procedure to the context then it wouldn't be an automated test.

Comment: I think you're confused.  The automation of your tests does not include automation of the creation of your DB objects.  How could it?  You're probably maintaining some sort of suite of scripts to create your database with.  One of those scripts will create your SPROC.  Use those scripts to make a test DB, then write some tests against it.

Comment: Well at the start of the unit test I create the database using datacontext.CreateDatabase() then populate it. Then I run my unit tests

Comment: Well you're going to have to use a different approach if you want to unit test your SPROC.  There are plenty of other ways to create your DB other than datacontext.CreateDatabase();  Usually developers have a test database *already* created for their unit tests

Answer (score 0):

The point of unit testing is not to touch your database, so if you have business logic based on the database, you need separate this dependency by using something like Repository pattern to return a value or values which you normally will get from the stored procedure.

Comment: He wants to actually unit test his SPROC.  To do that he *has* to touch his database.  Mocking your DB to provide specific results to test your business logic against is fine, but he wants to test the DB itself.

Comment: -1: please read carefully - he's testing the stored procedure, not the business logic.

Comment: i think what this answer is hinting at, is this is an *integration test*, not a *unit test*. You cannot unit test a stored procedure. You can unit test a Repository, but you should be providing mock objects.

Comment: This was a good answer given I had put it as unit test when I should really have been more clear and just written test. Have edited the question.

Comment: My point exactly. I have removed the unit test tag, and added the integration test ag.

Comment: @RPM: you can damned sure unit test a stored procedure! Why not? It's code.

Comment: I think the downvote was a bit harsh.  JW had good advice, just not in this particular instance.  +1 for trying to contribute intelligently

Comment: @John Saunders - arguably. Yeah, you can run it, see if it returns results. But a *unit test* should not be hitting anything except the unit of code you are executing. To test a stored proc you would need to go through at least a DAL and then hop over to the database, so it ceases to be a *unit*.

Comment: @RPM: you can populate a clean database with data for the specific test, then call the SP with particular parameters, check the results, then roll back the DB changes. Perfect unit tests. I just got through with dozens of them.

Comment: @RPM - Your argument is circular.  Unit tests cannot hit the DB.  Therefore, any tests that hit the DB are *a priori* not unit tests.  Unit tests CAN hit the database.  See Osherove's Art of Unit Tests, or Meszaros's xUnit Test Patterns.  Both state that unit tests may hit the DB *for purposes of testing the DB*